# Bluetooth connection in next activity

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth

i set up a bluetooth connection to a device in my mainactivity - that works.

now i wanna use the socket of the connected device in a second activity.

how can i transfer it? getExtra wont work :/

Thanks,
prexx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Local Bounded Service. See more about them here: [Bounded Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html).

The idea is that Service will open and manage bluetooth connection, while Activities will bind to this service and get bluetooth socket via interface that extends IBinder. This way lifecycle of Activity will not interfere with lifecycle of bluetooth socket, plus you can share you socket with as many activities as you want.

Comment: A bounded service is supposed to stop once the activity bounded to it is stopped right? If so how can one connection made in first activity be maintained through the next activity as well?